# Can't boot Windows 10 after installing Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, windows-server-2008

I installed windows server alongside Windows 10 and whenever I start my computer I don't have the option to boot Windows. When the computer starts it goes straight to windows server 2008 without giving me an OS selection menu. I still have all of the Windows 10 files on my hard drive, but Windows 10 has no way to boot.

Comment: use EasyBcd to add Windows 10 to the boot manager

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that earlier Windows boot managers cannot boot later Windows versions.

This has been always been the problem after you install an earlier Windows version when you have already a later Windows version installed on computer.

Use [Dual-boot repair tool to fix Windows 10 boot](https://www.boyans.net/dual-boot-repair-windows-10.html).